# Passing a variable between functions

Tags: java, android, parameter-passing

I'm new to android studio and Java. My app uses jsoup to pass the contents of a website into an array where each element gets displayed on swipable flashcards (like tinder)

I've got a problem where my app crashes when I try to pass the result of the variable 'words' from onPostExecute() (line 123) to String num on line 49. I want to take the output of the function in onPostExcecute and set it as String num but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
public class AppHome extends AppCompatActivity implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
    TextView texx;
    private ArrayList<String> al;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    private int i;
    String words;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_home);

        texx= findViewById(R.id.text1);
        new doit().execute();

        String num = words;
        String str[] = num.split(",");
        final ArrayList al = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str));

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.item, R.id.helloText, al );

        SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer = (SwipeFlingAdapterView) findViewById(R.id.frame);


        registerForContextMenu(flingContainer);


        flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        flingContainer.setFlingListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener() {
            @Override
            public void removeFirstObjectInAdapter() {
                // this is the simplest way to delete an object from the Adapter (/AdapterView)
                Log.d("LIST", "removed object!");
                al.remove(0);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLeftCardExit(Object dataObject) {
                //Do something on the left!
                //You also have access to the original object.
                //If you want to use it just cast it (String) dataObject
                Toast.makeText(AppHome.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRightCardExit(Object dataObject) {
                Toast.makeText(AppHome.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdapterAboutToEmpty(int itemsInAdapter) {
                // Ask for more data here
                al.add("XML ".concat(String.valueOf(i)));
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.d("LIST", "notified");
                i++;
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(float scrollProgressPercent) {
            }
        });

    }
    public class doit extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        //String words;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://screenscrape4top40.000webhostapp.com/").get();
                words=doc.text();
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            texx.setText(words);

            //String str = (words);
            //List<String> elephantList = Arrays.asList(str.split(","));
            //texx.setText(elephantList.toString());
            // texx.setText(elephantList);
        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: You should be using the Result argument instead of setting non-volatile mutable fields across threads

Comment: It would be great if you could post the log of your crash so that it is easier for us to understand what is the error that you are having. Thank you!

Comment: When defining async task subclass, use `AsynTask<Params, Progress, Result>`. Right now you're passing `Void` as type for all three. Changing result's type to `String` will allow `doInBackground()` to have the return type of `String`. It will also allow `onPostExecute()` to accept the `String` as argument.  Following article has code samples. https://medium.com/@suragch/android-asynctasks-99e501e637e5

Answer (score 0):

```
public class doit extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String words = "";
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://screenscrape4top40.000webhostapp.com/").get();
            words = doc.text();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return words;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String words) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        texx.setText(words);

        //String str = (words);
        //List<String> elephantList = Arrays.asList(str.split(","));
        //texx.setText(elephantList.toString());
        // texx.setText(elephantList);
    }
}
```

It should be fine now.

The problem is, you are not returning anything from the `doInBackground` method and hence you are not getting anything in the `onPostExecute` function.

You might consider checking the documentation for `AsyncTask` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask).

Answer (score 0):

In doInBackgroud() return the string(make sure it never beacome null) you want to use it on PostExecute()

also changed the data type of Parameter in onPostExecute method

onPostExecute(String Strs)

Then pass it to supper.OnPostExecute().

then u can use it.